# Gluon client-maven-plugin produces an exe file that does not run

Tags: java, maven, javafx, gluon

I'm currently trying to use Gluon's client-maven-plugin to build a native JavaFX app on Windows.

When I run mvn clean client:build, the build finishes successfully and produces a ~75MB exe file. However, when I try to run the app using mvn client:run, nothing happens and the terminal immediately tells me that my build was successful. I am not sure what's going on.

For reference, this is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>stl</groupId>
    <artifactId>threebodysimulation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>threebodysimulation</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>14.0.1</javafx.version>
        <mainClassName>stl.threebodysimulation.Launcher</mainClassName>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>oss-sonatype-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>stl.threebodysimulation.Launcher</mainClass>
                    <launcher>launcher</launcher>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.27-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reflectionList>
                        <list>javafx.application.Platform</list>
                        <list>javafx.concurrent.Task</list>
                        <list>javafx.fxml.FXML</list>
                        <list>javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader</list>
                        <list>javafx.fxml.Initializable</list>
                        <list>javafx.geometry.Insets</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.Parent</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.Scene</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.image.Image</list>
                        <list>javafx.stage.Stage</list>
                        <list>javafx.stage.Modality</list>
                        <list>javafx.stage.Window</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.image.Image</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.image.ImageView</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.layout.HBox</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.layout.StackPane</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.layout.VBox</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.layout.GridPane</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.control.Tab</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.control.TabPane</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.control.Button</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.control.Label</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.control.CheckBox</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.control.TextField</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.control.Tooltip</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.control.Separator</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.text.Font</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.paint.Color</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.shape.Circle</list>
                        <list>javafx.application.Application</list>
                        <list>javafx.util.Duration</list>
                        <list>org.apache.commons.math3.exception.NumberIsTooLargeException</list>
                        <list>org.apache.commons.math3.exception.NumberIsTooSmallException</list>
                        <list>org.apache.commons.math3.ode.nonstiff.DormandPrince853Integrator</list>
                        <list>org.apache.commons.math3.ode.FirstOrderDifferentialEquations</list>
                        <list>java.util.Arrays</list>
                        <list>java.util.HashMap</list>
                        <list>java.text.DecimalFormat</list>
                        <list>java.net.URL</list>
                        <list>java.util.ResourceBundle</list>
                        <list>stl.threebodysimulation.CanvasPanelFXMLController</list>
                        <list>stl.threebodysimulation.CanvasWrapper</list>
                        <list>stl.threebodysimulation.ErrorMessage</list>
                        <list>stl.threebodysimulation.InfoFXMLController</list>
                        <list>stl.threebodysimulation.InfoPanelFXMLController</list>
                        <list>stl.threebodysimulation.Launcher</list>
                        <list>stl.threebodysimulation.Listener</list>
                        <list>stl.threebodysimulation.MainApp</list>
                        <list>stl.threebodysimulation.NumberFormat</list>
                        <list>stl.threebodysimulation.ParameterFXMLController</list>
                        <list>stl.threebodysimulation.Particle</list>
                        <list>stl.threebodysimulation.ParticleDiffEq</list>
                        <list>stl.threebodysimulation.PopupWindowFXMLController</list>
                        <list>stl.threebodysimulation.SceneFXMLController</list>
                        <list>stl.threebodysimulation.SettingsPanelFXMLController</list>
                        <list>stl.threebodysimulation.SimulationSettings</list>
                        <list>stl.threebodysimulation.SimulationState</list>
                        <list>stl.threebodysimulation.TextFieldWrapper</list>
                    </reflectionList>
                    <mainClass>stl.threebodysimulation.Launcher</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I originally thought it might be a problem with the reflection list, so I added every class I had (and also every import I used in both java and FXML) to the list. It doesn't seem to help. The program runs normally when I use mvn compiler:compile resources:resources javafx:run.

Does anyone have any idea on where the problem might be? Thanks!

EDIT:

The Maven file references a "Launcher" class which looks like this:

```
package stl.threebodysimulation;

import javafx.application.Application;

/**
 * The class whose main method is called when the application is run.
 */
public class Launcher {
    /**
     * Runs the application.
     * @param args Terminal arguments.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(MainApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

This calls a MainApp class that looks like this:

```
package stl.threebodysimulation;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


/**
 * This class launches the UI of the app.
 */
public class MainApp extends Application {
    /**
     * @param stage The window that the app will be run in. Supplied by the Application parent class.
     * @throws Exception An exception that occurs if the layout files are not found. Should never occur.
     */
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // Set up the scene.fxml files and the CSS files. The inputs and outputs exist to implement the parent class Application.
        FXMLLoader appLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/scene.fxml"));
        Parent root = appLoader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1200, 900);

        // Load in CSS
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/bootstrap3.css").toExternalForm());

        // We don't want the window to be resizable, to save us the UI headache.
        stage.setResizable(false);

        // Icon of app
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image("/appIcon.png"));

        // Title of app
        stage.setTitle("Three-Body Simulation");

        // Stage the UI.
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

EDIT 2:

The logs for the error can be seen here:

```
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB] Exception in Application start method
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:517)
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  at com.oracle.svm.core.windows.WindowsJavaThreads.osThreadStartRoutine(WindowsJavaThreads.java:138)
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB] Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB] stl/threebodysimulation/settingsPanel.fxml:14
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB] stl/threebodysimulation/scene.fxml:14
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB] 
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2629)
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2607)
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2470)
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$IncludeElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1154)
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:754)
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2726)
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2556)
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2470)
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2439)
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  at stl.threebodysimulation.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:23)
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:101)
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIJavaCallWrappers.jniInvoke_VA_LIST:Ljava_lang_Runnable_2_0002erun_00028_00029V(JNIJavaCallWrappers.java:0)
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(WinApplication.java)
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  ... 3 more
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Including "resource:stl/threebodysimulation/settingsPanel.fxml" in "resource:stl/threebodysimulation/settingsPanel.fxml" created cyclic reference.
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$IncludeElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1146)
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:754)
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2726)
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2556)
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] [SUB]  ... 20 more
[Wed Jun 03 18:58:32 EDT 2020][FINE] Result for run until end: 0
```

A similar error can be found [here.](https://github.com/gluonhq/client-gradle-plugin/issues/13)

Line 14 of scene.fxml looks like this:

```
<fx:include fx:id="settingsPanel" source="settingsPanel.fxml" />
```

Comment: If you have an exe, try to run it from the file explorer or from a terminal. See if there are any errors logged.

Comment: @JoséPereda I tried to run it in Windows PowerShell, but nothing happened. It didn't show any errors or logs... it just didn't do anything.

Comment: Do you have an Application class, with a main method?

Comment: @JoséPereda There is a main class but it is not Application. It has a main method that launches another class that is Application. I've added an edit to the main post that has the code in both files.

Comment: Try `mvn client:run` again, and check the  `target/client/x86_64-windows/gvm/log/client-debug0.log` file, for the RUN task. See if you find the logs and any possible exception.

Comment: @JoséPereda Ah, I see what you are referring to now. The errors appear to be the same as those found on https://github.com/gluonhq/client-gradle-plugin/issues/13. There is a "LoadException" that traces to an "IOException" that points out a "cyclic reference" where there isn't actually a cyclic reference. Is there a fix for this issue? I've added some specifics in an edit to the post.

Comment: Not so far, you may need to remove the `fx:include`, and add it via code.

Comment: @JoséPereda Okay, that's unfortunate. Thanks for the advice, I'll get to working on that.